# Check if std Class element exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
            $UIDInfo = users::getUserInfo($UID);
        print_r($UIDInfo);

        if(property_exists('castleName', $UIDInfo)){
            die('UIP Member');
        } elseif(!property_exists('castleName', $UIDInfo)){
                die('Not UIP member');
        }
```

I want to do a check to see if there is an element [castleName] but my code is not working.  How can I check if that [castleName] exists.  From the same query that element will not be returned if the user is not a member.

The print_r returns this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [uID] => 1 
        [username] => wdeswardt 
        [memRequestID] => 1 
        [castleName] => WilliamNZ 
        [emailAddress] => the users email address 
    ) 
)
```

Not UIP member

Comment: Well, it's not an `stdClass` instance, but an array. Use `array_key_exists`

Comment: Because it returns that the user is not a member where the user is a member

Comment: I tried that and that also does not work

Comment: Sidenote: checking `if( something ){ }elseif{ !something ){ }` is the same as `if(something){}else{}`

Comment: `$UIDInfo` is an array of a single element. So your object is at `$UIDInfo[0]`

Comment: `property_exists` doesn't work because the parent container is an array, just add the dimension needed: `$UIDInfo[0]`, that points to the object, then make your property checking, blah blah

Comment: $UIDInfo = users::getUserInfo($UID);
   print_r($UIDInfo);
   if(array_key_exists('castleName', $UIDInfo)){
    die('UIP Member');
   } elseif(!array_key_exists('castleName', $UIDInfo)){
     die('Not UIP member');
   }

Comment: i already edited the array dump for everyone see what it really looks like, very easy to debug now

Comment: @Ghost which just proves the point that indentation/formatting (lack of it) - is the source of 95% of problems of beginners.

Comment: Thanks its working now.